# Duplicating the values of a column in ultrawingrid

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

[image]

I have a grid that gets its values from database, I have two columns with these values coming from database, I want to duplicate the values of second column with the values in first column. Is there any way to do it on the front end...

I am trying to edit the value on the second column and compare it with the first column values, it should always be less than the value in first column and then only user can be able to save it.

Below is the code

```
ds = new DataSet("DS1");
DS1= GetActiveCodes("DT1");
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Select", typeof(bool));
dc.DefaultValue = true;
DS1.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc);
grid.SetDataBinding(DS1, "DT1");
```

Thank you

Comment: can you show any code.. and if you are using a datatable this can easily be done by setting the value of the DataTables `ItemArray` 
something like this `dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1] = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0]` doing this in a foreach loop of the `foreach(var dr in dt.Rows[0].ItemArray)`

Comment: put the code in your original question.. edit your question and paste it there..

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: ok so based on the code you have posted.. you have `Ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dc)` is that populated with data as you have depicted in the picture..? if so then you need to do a foreach loop as I have stated in my previous comment on your DataTable.. have you tried that..?

Comment: @MethodMan dc is a checkbox column that is added to the dataset before binding on to the grid. I have it on the grid on front end, its just that I did not include that column in my screen shot.

Comment: so what are you wanting to do now.. I still don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @MethodMan I want the same values on second column as first column.

Comment: do the following 
`DS1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Amount"] = DS1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Balance"];` do this in a foreach loop for `DataRow`

Comment: @MethodMan Can you please let me know how to achieve the same with ItemArray? if that is efficient way of doing it..

Comment: look at my last comment and use the `DataTable.Rows[0]["ColumnName"]` approach doing a foreach loop on `foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)` this is more than enough to get you started try something now and let me know what you have issues with

Comment: I could do it...Thank you so much for the reply...@MethodMan

Comment: did you get it to work..?

Comment: yes I got it by referencing it this way: foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) 
                {
                    dr["Amount"] = dr["Balance"];
                }

Comment: I have put in the answer how it should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{ 
    dr["Amount"] = dr["Balance"]; 
}
```

Comment: I have one more question regarding the same column, if you see the amount column it just has two decimal places after decimal point, how can I make it 4 zeroes after decimal point? IS there any way to do from front end?

Comment: you can do this in the backed by using string.Format function here is an example in your foreach loop 
`dr["Amount"] = string.Format("{0:###.0000}", Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Amount"]))`;